# What does it mean when an OCaml variable starts with `#`? (hash sign/pound sign)?

Tags: types, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

I cam across this in a pattern match

`| {call_name = #bundle_source; _ }`

[source](https://github.com/bloomberg/bucklescript/blob/master/jscomp/syntax/ast_external_attributes.ml#L743)

Earlier in the code, `bundle_source` is defined as a type (`type bundle_source = ...`).

So what does the hash sign mean? Does `{call_name = #bundle_source }` in the pattern match mean that the value of `call_name` is expected to have type `bundle_source`?

I searched [the manual](http://caml.inria.fr/distrib/ocaml-4.04/ocaml-4.04-refman.pdf) for "hash sign" and "pound sign" but found nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a shorthand for constructing patterns that match a collection of polymorphic variant values.

The documentation is in [Section 6.6](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.03/patterns.html) of the OCaml manual:

> If the type `` [('a,'b,…)] typeconstr = [ ` tag-name1  typexpr1 | … | ` tag-namen  typexprn] `` is defined, then the pattern `#typeconstr` is a shorthand for the following or-pattern: `` ( `tag-name1(_ :  typexpr1) | … | ` tag-namen(_ :  typexprn)) ``. It matches all values of type `[< typeconstr ]`.

```
# type b = [`A | `B];;
type b = [ `A | `B ]
# let f x =
  match x with
  | #b -> "yes"
  | _ -> "no";;
val f : [> b ] -> string = <fun>
# f `A;;
- : string = "yes"
# f `Z;;
- : string = "no"
```

(I was not familiar with this notation either.)

Answer (score 3):

As a complement of the use of `#typeconstr` in patterns, in a type expression `#class-path` indicates a subtype of the class `#class_path`. For instance, with

```
class c = object method m = () end
class d = object inherit c method n = () end
let f (x:c) = ()
let g (x:#c) = ()
```

the call `f (new d)` fails with

```
Error: This expression has type d but an expression was expected of type c.
The second object type has no method n
```

since `f` expects an object of type `c`  exactly, whereas `g (new d)` is accepted by the type-checker since `d` is a a subclass of `c` (note that `g (object method m = () end) would also be accepted).